# How can I start a function everytime the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

*(Sorry in advance if there are any english mistake)*
Hi everyone, I'm working on a simple Chrome extension to edit some graphics and texts related fields of a website (Freshdesk) that I can't modify from the website itself because the code is proprietary.
My problem is, to make the function that replace the texts be active everytime the pages are displayed, I'm using a setInterval() with 100 ms of delay, which kinda does the job but it's not optimal, because the function runs like thousands of times in a few seconds.

```
function main() {
  console.log('main started');

  setInterval(changeText, 100); //(Not optimized)
}

function changeText() {
  // replace 'Group' with 'Sector'' in the ticket tab visual
  $('.ember-power-select-placeholder.label-field').each(function(x){
    var new_text = $(this).text().replace("Group", "Sector");
    $(this).text(new_text);
    console.log('function started');
  })
}

main();
```

As you can see from the screenshots and the code above, in this simple case I wanna change the text from 
[Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs6jL.png)
to 
[Sector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCB8.png)
and, as you can see, the code works, but [if we take a look at the console..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBPbd.png) (this is after like 5 seconds).

I already tried some function to make the js run as soon as the page loads just once, but none of them seem to work for me.
Do you have any tip to fix this situation?

EDIT: Here is the manifest.json too

```
{
    "name": "DAN-Patch",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation", 
        "activeTab", 
        "background",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "matches": ["https://gestionaledan.freshdesk.com/*", "https://gestionaledan.freshworks.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "content.js"],
            "css": ["stylesheet.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `main` and just add `changeText()` to the code.

Comment: use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` if you want your function to run once

Comment: @firatozcevahir the problem with setTimeout is that it works only the first time the page is loaded. After that, if I go to another page and jump back to the first one it doesn't load the function again. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @ScottMarcus it doesn't seems to work. The console.log appears if I write that first in the function body, but then the text doesn't get replace on the website

Comment: I suspect that has more to do with `$(this)` not referencing what you think it does than the code running as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: You can try: ```window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {console.log("loaded!");});```

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see, the fact is that I've been using javascript for only a week so I'm not that expert. Do you know a better way to write this code?

Comment: I'd start by adding this in your loop to determine what `this` is: `console.log($(this));`

Comment: @WillBlack the text doesn't change by using that, even tho theoretically it should. (It show the console.log)

Comment: @ScottMarcus it shows `div.ember-power-select-placeholder.label-field` which is the correct field where that text is, so it shouldn't be the main problem I guess

Comment: I would try @WillBlack suggestion and put your code into an event handler. Specifically, I'd put it in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded, changeText);`

Answer (score 0):

use this to reduce the number of processes:

```js
function main() {
    console.log('main started');

    let exa = setInterval(function () {
        let el = $('.ember-power-select-placeholder.label-field'),
            all = 0;
        el.each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == "Group") {
                // replace 'Group' with 'Sector'' in the ticket tab visual
                var new_text = $(this).text().replace("Group", "Sector");
                $(this).text(new_text);
                console.log('function started');
                all ++;
            }
        });
        if (all == 0) {
            clearInterval(exa);
        }
    }, 100); //(Not optimized)
}

main();
```